# how to save and get comment meta_key and meta_value for specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 pages. One is `devices` and the other is `cars`. I also have `detail_car` page and `detail_device` page which are show the detail of each element relate to the name. I want to save and get comments for each specific devices and cars separately. For example in the `detail_device` page with and `$id=2`, when users write a comment about `device` whit the `id` of `2`, I want to save this comment as `meta_key=device_id` and `meta_value`=2.
then after approving comment, it'll be enable in the detail_device with id =2 not to other devices.

```
function add_custom_comment_page( $comment_id, $page, $element_id ) {

    $page_array = ['devices', 'cars'];
    if (!empty($page) && in_array($page, $page_array)) {
        add_comment_meta($comment_id, $page.'_id', $element_id);
    }

}
```

how and where to pass `$page`?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the comments in with get_comment in your template.

[get_comment](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comment)

Comment: my pages are created by shortcodes and I fetch id from query string.